# How can I add one more day to the Jquery UI Datepicker date range?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code that works fine if I enter the dates, but if I click on ".from_date" and leave it empty, I have this error: "Cannot read property 'setDate' of null". What could I do to avoid the error?

```
    $(".from_date").datepicker({
      minDate: 0,
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function() {
      var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
      var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1));
        $(".to_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", newMin);
        return $(".to_date").datepicker("show");
      }
    });
 $(".to_date").datepicker({
      minDate: '+1D',
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      numberOfMonths: 1
    });
```

Comment: The error suggests that `minDate` is `null`. Description for `getDate`: *Returns the current date for the datepicker or null if no date has been selected.* Hence the `null` value for `minDate`. Advise a default date.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".from_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function(dText) {
      var minDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/y", dText);
      if (minDate != null) {
        var newMin = new Date(minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 8));
        $(".to_date").datepicker("option", "minDate", newMin);
      }
    }
  }).datepicker("setDate", "+1w");
  $(".to_date").datepicker({
    minDate: "+8d",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",
    defaultDate: "+8d",
    numberOfMonths: 1
  }).datepicker("setDate", "+8d");;
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="from" class="from_date" name="from">
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="to" class="to_date" name="to">
```

Here, we pre-populate a date with `setDate` method. This ensures that there is a Date in either field so if the User selects a date or does not, they can proceed without error.

Comment: Also I would advise reviewing the following: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: If you clean "from" you'll get the same error, try it

Comment: @tonydeleon as I stated in my comment, `getDate` will return `null` if the field is empty. This leaves `minDate` = `null` and `minDate.setDate()` will not exists.

Comment: @tonydeleon added a condition to help prevent a `minDate` being `null`.

Comment: Excellent @Twisty now it's working ! thank you very much